# Remove or Add button on Standard New Record Object

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, button

When I click on "New" button on Account Object I receive a Modal to insert a new Account:

[image]

I know that is possible to create a page with Account's StandardController, go to buttons and links and simply override that button with your VF page and, in this way, override the standard button.

So, now I would ask if is possible to add/remove custom botton.
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? But I guess its not possible to manage them unless page is overridden, sort of like the standard buttons in new/edit screen of classic UI.

Comment: I would add a "Check Button" to execute some custom Apex code and give a feedback to user on form.

Comment: I guess a trigger would be a best place to add such kind of validation/logic. Lets wait for others to share their thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to add custom buttons on standard edit layout, you can accomplish this using custom VF page.